# How can I define and use my own custom services in Nuxt with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

When making my TS Nuxt App I realized it made sense to define an ApiService that communicates with the API, so I created a folder named `services` and put my service file in it, so I had `services/api-service.ts`.

The content of the file was something like

```
import axios from 'axios'    
export default class ApiService {
      static someRequest(data: dataType) {
        return axios.get("someEndpoint", data)
      }
}
```

I tried importing it in my layout where I needed it, as such:

```
import ApiService from '@/services/api-service'
...
  created () {
  ...
    ApiService.someRequest(data)
      .then(someMethod)
      .catch(console.log)
  }
```

and although my IDE didn't complain, Nuxt couldn't find it when compiling, giving me an error message like

```
This dependency was not found:                                                                friendly-errors 09:20:35
                                                                                              friendly-errors 09:20:35
* @/services/api-service in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/@nuxt/components/dist/loader.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./layouts/default.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
```

I've tried to include it as a module, but apparently modules are limited to exporting functions, hence exporting classes is a no go. Making a plugin does not seem like the logical solution either. How can I use a custom service class such as my ApiService in a TS Nuxt App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head against the wall for about a day I found my answer [in this github issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8015#issuecomment-687716279).

Apparently the version of `@nuxt/typescript-runtime` that shipped with my `create-nuxt-app` generated app with TypeScript was `"@nuxt/typescript-runtime": "^1.0.0"` which is outdated.

To fix this I ran

```
yarn add @nuxt/typescript-runtime --dev
```

in my terminal to upgrade to `"@nuxt/typescript-runtime": "^2.0.0"`, and now my import works just fine as is. I see that [the package was bumped](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/pull/599) a little over a month ago so hopefully nobody else runs into the same problem, and if they do I hope this answer can be of help.